# How to logout the user on apollo-link-error in react-native app?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, apollo-client

To navigate around in my react-native app, I am using "react-navigation".

With the code below, I can successfully intercept all necessary errors that are coming from the server.

```
const linkError = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    // Logout user
    // 1. Issue logout mutation
    // 2. Navigate to Login screen
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
      )
    );
  }
  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([linkError, stateLink, authLink, httpLink]),
  cache,
});
```

The question is how to navigate the user to "Login" screen and issue "Logout" mutation if an error happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your code to have `client` returned from a hook. It could be similar to this:

```
export const useApolloClient = () => {
  // Assuming `logout` is a function that removes the user token
  const { logout } = useAuth();

  return useMemo(() => {
    const linkError = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) => {
          if (message === 'Unauthorized') {
            // Or whatever may be the reason for logging out
            logout()
          }

          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
          )
        });
      }
      if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    });

    return new ApolloClient({
      link: ApolloLink.from([linkError, stateLink, authLink, httpLink]),
      cache,
    });
  }, [logout]);
};
```

A couple of comments on your comments:

// Logout user
// 1. Issue logout mutation

Not sure what you mean by `logout mutation` - I suppose you store a token that represents a signed-in user.

// 2. Navigate to Login screen

If you use `react-navigation`, I don't think that manual navigation would be a good practice. According to [their documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow), you should simply return the navigator presenting `Login screen` based on `isSignedIn`. I would suggest using a JWT token (if that's the supposed flow) as a `isSignedIn` flag.